# Checking for maximum value in a Pandas series, where the series contains letters that have numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 6 columns, each giving a 'status'. These statuses can be any of the following: `T, N, 0, U, D, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8`.
Where for the purposes of comparison, T > N > 0 > U > D > 1 > 2...

What I am trying to achieve, is to create a new column, `WORST STATUS`, that can pick out the maximum value from this list (something like a `df.max()` where the max method can identify that "U" is greater than 0.

I know I can probably contain this all in an if-else and do an element-wise comparison, but I wondered if there was anything more "clean"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ordered Categorical`, so is possible use `max` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col':[1, 2, 3, 4, 'N', 'N', 0, 'U', 'D', 5, 6, 8]})

cats = ['T', 'N', 0, 'U', 'D', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], ordered=True, categories=cats[::-1])

print (df['col'])
Categories (12, object): [8 < 6 < 5 < 4 ... 'U' < 0 < 'N' < 'T']

#in data is no T, so N is maximal
print (df['col'].max())
N
```

If need processing multiple columns:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, ordered=True, categories=cats[::-1]))
```

And then:

```
print (df[cols].max(axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jezrael this looks really promising but does it work for trying to get the max value across a row. I imagine I can change the first argument in ```df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], ordered=True, categories=cats[::-1])``` to ```df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df.iloc[i], ordered=True, categories=cats[::-1])``` and loop over each record?

Comment: @StephenMason - If need processing rows, then need `df.iloc[i] = pd.Categorical(df.iloc[i], ordered=True, categories=cats[::-1])` ?